# nginx: how can I redirect http to https in proxied requests?

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have the following server block:

```
server {

    listen 192.0.2.1:443 ssl;
    listen 192.0.2.1:80;
    server_name support.example.com;
    ssl_certificate           /etc/ssl/certs/support.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/ssl/private/support.example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' cloud.example.com example.com";
    access_log            /var/log/nginx/support.log;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_pass          https://support.example.com;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;
    }
     location ~ .well-known {

             root /srv/web;
    }
}
```

I'd want to every request except `location ~ .well-known` was redirect to https, I've tried with redirect directive but that did not work. I would like that every time that client requests a non-http request was redirected to https://support.example.com.

**Note**: I'd want to avoid to create a new virtual server for non-http requests.

Answer (score 0):

The server block below will catch http requests for support.example.com and redirect to https.

***Note***: Before modifying configuration files **always** make a back. If something goes wrong you can rollback more easily.

```
server {
    listen 192.168.0.100:80;
    server_name support.example.com
    return 301 https://support.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Below will catch both http & https requests for www.support.example.com to https support.example.com. Whilst this isn't important when using subdomains such as in your example, it is useful when you want www.example.com directed to example.com. I am only including it here because it might be useful to you or someone else.

```
server {
    listen 192.168.0.100:80;
    listen 192.168.0.100:443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;

    # SSL Certs stuff for www.example.com goes here

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Once you have caught all the requests you can process in the usual way.

```
server {
    listen 192.168.0.100:443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    # SSL Stuff and other requirements go here

}
```

All three of the above can be placed into /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf

After making changes Nginx can check your modifications using the following command.

```
sudo nginx -t

You should get the following output;

nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

You can reload Nginx using the *-s reload*

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not answer my question...

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted to redirect http to https. Although I originally missed the bit about "except location ~ .well-known". Oops! :)